# Show DatePicker hourAndMinute on print statement SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following DatePicker:

```
Section(header: Text("Notifications will be triggered only between \(startDay) and \(endDay)")) {
                    DatePicker("Start day", selection: $startDay, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                    DatePicker("End day", selection: $endDay, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                }
```

[image]

How on the string interpolation text can I display only the hourAndMinute component?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DateFormatter, for example something like:

```
var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    return formatter
}

Section(header: Text("Notifications will be triggered only between \(dateFormatter.string(from: startDay)) and \(dateFormatter.string(from: endDay))")) {
                DatePicker("Start day", selection: $startDay, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                DatePicker("End day", selection: $endDay, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            }
```

Comment: I had to change the `HH:mm` to `h:mm a`, but everything else is good. Thank you